# Jqgrid Pass select rows column values to dataurl

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to pass column values to php load the select item on the edit form based on the column values.

```
dataUrl:'includes/Opera_classif.php?Op=local&id=' +ID +Description +id_local
```

**JS**

```
mtype: 'GET', 
colNames: [ "ID","Descrição","ID Local", "Local","Select Local"],
colModel: [
{name:'ID',index:'ID', width:20, sorttype:"int"},
{name:'Description',index:'Description', width:150, editable: true,editrules:{required:true}},
{name:'id_local',index:'id_local',hidden:true, width:20, editable: true,editrules:{required:true}},
{name:'Local_Description',index:'Local_Description', width:100, editable: true,editrules:{required:true}},
{
    name:'escolhe_local',index:'escolhe_local', width:80,resizable:true, hidden:true, editrules:{edithidden: true }, 
    align:"left",sorttype:"text",editable:true,edittype:"select",
    editoptions:{dataUrl:'includes/Opera_classif.php?Op=local'} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use `dataUrl` defined as function (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/support-dataurl-as-function) and [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/108d04eeabbb2eb4bd24a14415a892a68604a1fa)). The function `dataUrl` get 3 parameter (the first is the `rowid`, the second is the value from the current column - `Local_Description` in your case) and `this` will be initialized to DOM of the grid (so you can use `$(this).jqGrid("getRowData", rowid)` or `$(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "Description")` for example). In the way you can generate any `dataUrl` value which you need.