# Jqgrid dynamic dropdownlist based on value in some other column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have a JQGrid with 3 columns. The third column, I want it as a dropdownlist based on some value in the  second column. Is this Possible?

Also in the JQGrid demo, do add a dropdown we need to set the edittype to "select" and pass the values in JSON.

```
edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"FE:FedEx;IN:InTime;TN:TNT;AR:ARAMEX"}},
```

My next question is how to pass values to this column from a model object in the format it is expecting.

Comment: see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17410568/315935) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935) which demonstrates how to use `beforeProcessing` to modify `editoptions.value` dynamically (using for example `setColProp`).

Comment: public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listCode { get; set; }

Comment: colNames: ['Column1','Column2','Status','Column4','Column5'],
                colModel: [
                        { name: 'Field1' },
                        { name: 'Field2' },
                        { name: 'Status' },
                        { name: 'Field4' },
                        {
                             name: 'Field5', width: 80, search: false, // Want this either as a drop down or a text box based on value in "Status" column

Comment: If it is a dropdown then I want the dropdown to be populated from the below model object.

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listCode { get; set; }

Is there any example for the above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dataUrl` or `postData` property of [editoption](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions) defined as function. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24981547/315935) or [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/404) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14952082/315935). If you need to send standard URL parameters like `/mySetectUrl?status=StatusValue` then you can use

```
name: "Field5", edittype: "select",
editoptions: {
    // it produces URL like /mySetectUrl?status=StatusValue
    dataUrl: "/mySetectUrl",
    postData: function (rowid, value, name) {
        return { status: $(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "Status") };
    }
}
```

If you need to construct some another URL like `/mySetectUrl/StatusValue` you can use `dataUrl` defined as function:

```
name: "Field5", edittype: "select",
editoptions: {
    // it produces URL like /mySetectUrl/StatusValue
    dataUrl: function (rowid, value, name) {
        return "/mySetectUrl/" +
            encodeURIComponent($(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "Status"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg, but the above gives me a dropdown, how about if I need a text box instead of dropdown based on the value.

Comment: @Sid13: You are welcome! What you want to do with the text box? It will be automatically filled with the value of the cell which you edit. You can use `dataInit` to make any other modification.

Comment: Oleg, basically based on the value in the status field, I will either populate a dropdown which the user will select a value from OR I will just display a text with some information on it.Thanks

Comment: Also the text I want to display in the column should come from the server. Thanks